# Solr query result mismatch with analysis page

Tags: solr

I'm facing some issue on Solr query time.

I'm trying search some keyword (term),it is giving me proper result in analysis page, But in query it does not return same result as analysis page.

I'm using Solr 6.4.2

These are my solr data:

```
{Id:1,Name:"Test k504"}
{Id:2,Name:"Test 504"}
{Id:3,Name:"Test k504-ink"}
```

search term and result like below.

```
Query   Term       current result(Id)    required result
1.      k504          1,3                   1,2,3
2.      504           1,2,3                 1,2,3(it's ok)
3.      k504-ink      3                     1,2,3
```

My Analysis page result like below image.
[image]

#### schema.xml

```xml
...
<fieldType name="solr_query" class="solr.TextField" 
positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">        
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"      
generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" 
catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">        
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"  
generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" 
catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"
            preserveOriginal="1" />
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
 <fields>
<field name="Id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"  
/>
<field name="Name" type="solr_query" indexed="true" stored="true"  
 required="false" />
 </fields>
 <copyField source="Name" dest="solr_query"/>
...
```

Update 1:
**Solr Query**

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/myCore/select?fl=Name,Id&indent=on&q=Name:504&wt=json



<filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="10" />
```

**Update 2:**

#### solrconfig.xml

```xml
<config>  
  <luceneMatchVersion>5.0.0</luceneMatchVersion>
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" 
   regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*
   \.jar" />
   <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/clustering/lib/" 
   regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-
   clustering-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/langid/lib/"  
   regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*
   \.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/velocity/lib" 
   regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*
   \.jar" />
  <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}</dataDir>  
  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory"                     
   class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory}"/>  
  <codecFactory class="solr.SchemaCodecFactory"/>  
  <schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
  <indexConfig>    
    <lockType>${solr.lock.type:native}</lockType>    
     <infoStream>true</infoStream>
  </indexConfig>
  <jmx />
  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">
    <updateLog>
      <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
    </updateLog> 
     <autoCommit> 
       <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime> 
       <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
     </autoCommit>
     <autoSoftCommit> 
       <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime> 
     </autoSoftCommit>
  </updateHandler>  
  <query>
    <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>
    <slowQueryThresholdMillis>-1</slowQueryThresholdMillis>
    <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
                 size="512"
                 initialSize="512"
                 autowarmCount="0"/>
    <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                     size="512"
                     initialSize="512"
                     autowarmCount="0"/>  
    <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                   size="512"
                   initialSize="512"
                   autowarmCount="0"/>    
    <!-- custom cache currently used by block join --> 
    <cache name="perSegFilter"
      class="solr.search.LRUCache"
      size="10"
      initialSize="0"
      autowarmCount="10"
      regenerator="solr.NoOpRegenerator" />   
    <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>
   <queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>
   <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>
    <listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">
      </arr>
    </listener>
    <listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">
        <lst>
          <str name="q">static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml</str>
        </lst>
      </arr>
    </listener>
    <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>
    <maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>
  </query>
  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="false" > 
    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" 
                    multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000"
                    formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048"
                    addHttpRequestToContext="false"/>
    <httpCaching never304="true" />
  </requestDispatcher>
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler" >    
     <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
      <str name="field">Name</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>     
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxcollations">5</str> 
      <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativetermcount">2</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxresultsforsuggest">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxcollationtries">5</str>
     </lst>  
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>    
 </requestHandler>
  <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="indent">true</str>
       <str name="df">Name</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
   <requestHandler name="/export" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="rq">{!xport}</str>
      <str name="wt">xsort</str>
      <str name="distrib">false</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>query</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler> 
  <initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">Name</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>
  <initParams path="/update/json/docs">
    <lst name="defaults">      
      <str name="srcField">_src_</str>
      <str name="mapUniqueKeyOnly">true</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>
  <requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>
      <!-- capture link hrefs but ignore div attributes -->
      <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
      <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
    <requestHandler name="/analysis/field" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" />
    <requestHandler name="/analysis/document" 
                  class="solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler" 
                  startup="lazy" />
    <!-- Echo the request contents back to the client -->
     <requestHandler name="/debug/dump" class="solr.DumpRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str> 
     <str name="echoHandler">true</str>
    </lst>
    </requestHandler>  
     <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
    </requestHandler>                 
    <requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="qt">/select</str>
      <str name="q">*:*</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>  
    <requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >  
     </requestHandler>  
  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">solr_query</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">SpellContent</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
    </lst>    
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>      
      <str name="field">SpellContent</str>
      <str name="combineWords">true</str>
      <str name="breakWords">false</str>
      <int name="maxChanges">10</int>     
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">Name</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>       
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>         
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>  
  <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent" 
                   enable="${solr.suggester.enabled:false}"     >
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>      
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">cat</str>
      <str name="weightField">price</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" 
                  startup="lazy" enable="${solr.suggester.enabled:false}" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
  <searchComponent name="tvComponent" class="solr.TermVectorComponent"/>
  <requestHandler name="/tvrh" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="tv">true</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>tvComponent</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
  <searchComponent name="clustering"
                   enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:false}"
                   class="solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent" >
    <lst name="engine">
      <str name="name">lingo</str>
      <str name="carrot.algorithm">
     org.carrot2.clustering.lingo.LingoClusteringAlgorithm</str>
      <str name="carrot.resourcesDir">clustering/carrot2</str>
    </lst>
    <!-- An example definition for the STC clustering algorithm. -->
    <lst name="engine">
      <str name="name">stc</str>
      <str 
     name="carrot.algorithm">
    org.carrot2.clustering.stc.STCClusteringAlgorithm</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="engine">
      <str name="name">kmeans</str>
      <str    name="carrot.algorithm">
    org.carrot2.clustering.kmeans.BisectingKMeansClusteri
    ngAlgorithm</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
  <requestHandler name="/clustering"
                  startup="lazy"
                  enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:false}"
                  class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="clustering">true</bool>
      <bool name="clustering.results">true</bool>      
      <str name="carrot.title">name</str>     
      <str name="carrot.url">id</str>      
      <str name="carrot.snippet">features</str>
      <!-- Apply highlighter to the title/ content and use this for 
    clustering. -->
      <bool name="carrot.produceSummary">true</bool>
      <!-- the maximum number of labels per cluster -->
      <!--<int name="carrot.numDescriptions">5</int>-->
      <!-- produce sub clusters -->
      <bool name="carrot.outputSubClusters">false</bool>
      <!-- Configure the remaining request handler parameters. -->
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="qf">
        Name
      </str>
      <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
      <str name="rows">10</str>
      <str name="fl">*,score</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>clustering</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
  <searchComponent name="terms" class="solr.TermsComponent"/>
  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the terms component -->
  <requestHandler name="/terms" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
     <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="terms">true</bool>
      <bool name="distrib">false</bool>
    </lst>     
    <arr name="components">
      <str>terms</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
  <searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
    <!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
    <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
  </searchComponent>
  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the elevator component -->
  <requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>elevator</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler> 
    <searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
    <highlighting>
      <!-- Configure the standard fragmenter -->
      <!-- This could most likely be commented out in the "default" case -->
      <fragmenter name="gap" 
                  default="true"
                  class="solr.highlight.GapFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <int name="hl.fragsize">100</int>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- A regular-expression-based fragmenter 
           (for sentence extraction) 
        -->
      <fragmenter name="regex" 
                  class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- slightly smaller fragsizes work better because of slop -->
          <int name="hl.fragsize">70</int>
          <!-- allow 50% slop on fragment sizes -->
          <float name="hl.regex.slop">0.5</float>
          <!-- a basic sentence pattern -->
          <str name="hl.regex.pattern">[-\w ,/\n\&quot;&apos;]{20,200}</str>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>
      <!-- Configure the standard formatter -->
      <formatter name="html" 
                 default="true"
                 class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em>]]></str>
          <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </formatter>
      <!-- Configure the standard encoder -->
      <encoder name="html" 
               class="solr.highlight.HtmlEncoder" />
      <!-- Configure the standard fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="simple" 
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragListBuilder"/>      
      <!-- Configure the single fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="single" 
                       class="solr.highlight.SingleFragListBuilder"/>      
      <!-- Configure the weighted fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="weighted" 
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.WeightedFragListBuilder"/>      
      <!-- default tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="default" 
                        default="true"
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">            
        <!-- 
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.multiValuedSeparatorChar">/</str>
        </lst>
        -->
      </fragmentsBuilder>
      <!-- multi-colored tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="colored" 
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[
               <b style="background:yellow">,<b style="background:lawgreen">,
               <b style="background:aquamarine">,<b 
   style="background:magenta">,
               <b style="background:palegreen">,<b style="background:coral">,
               <b style="background:wheat">,<b style="background:khaki">,
               <b style="background:lime">,<b 
   style="background:deepskyblue">]]></str>
          <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</b>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </fragmentsBuilder>      
      <boundaryScanner name="default" 
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.bs.maxScan">10</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.chars">.,!? &#9;&#10;&#13;</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>      
      <boundaryScanner name="breakIterator" 
                       class="solr.highlight.BreakIteratorBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- type should be one of CHARACTER, WORD(default), LINE and  
   SENTENCE -->
          <str name="hl.bs.type">WORD</str>
          <!-- language and country are used when constructing Locale object.    
    -->
          <!-- And the Locale object will be used when getting instance of 
   BreakIterator -->
          <str name="hl.bs.language">en</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.country">US</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>
    </highlighting>
  </searchComponent>
  <queryResponseWriter name="json" class="solr.JSONResponseWriter">
    <str name="content-type">text/plain; charset=UTF-8</str>
  </queryResponseWriter>  
    <queryResponseWriter name="velocity" class="solr.VelocityResponseWriter" 
   startup="lazy">
      <str name="template.base.dir">${velocity.template.base.dir:}</str>
    </queryResponseWriter>  
  <queryResponseWriter name="xslt" class="solr.XSLTResponseWriter">
    <int name="xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds">5</int>
  </queryResponseWriter>
  <admin>
    <defaultQuery>*:*</defaultQuery>
  </admin>
   </config>
```

I tried simple Solr query but not get any correct result with below filter as well

NGramFilterFactory

WordDelimiterFilterFactory

So please let me know if I'm missing something into that,

Thanks,

Comment: show the exact query url you are using, with all params etc

Comment: I don't see any `NGramFilterFactory` in your `analyzer` chain. So it is not clear how do you have used it. And again, will help if you show exactly what kind of  Solr Query you've tried.

Comment: @ Persimmonium, @freedev : Please check mu Update 1

Comment: It is not clear in which analyzer chain `NGramFilterFactory` is used.

Comment: @freedev I just tried for alternative solution with  NGramFilterFactory but not get any luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that field "Name" in your schema has type "text". 
You should correct the type into "solr_query".

```
<field name="Name" type="solr_query" indexed="true" stored="true"  
 required="false" />
```

Remember that after the schema change you have to reload the core or restart Solr and then reload the entire collection data.

And again,

```
<copyField source="Name" dest="solr_query"/>
```

This configuration line seems to be useless, because it copy the content of field Name into a field solr_query. But as far as I know you don't have such field solr_query.

You have only declared a type named solr_query.

Comment: I have tried your solution but not get any luck.Please check my updated question.

Comment: After this your search query should work. My last request: add in your post the solrconfig.xml.